# Quick way to print negative dollar values

Tags: perl, printf

I use this currently

```
 $Profit = -8.2 ;
 printf("%8s",sprintf("\$%0.2f",$Profit)).
```

which prints

```
 $-8.2
```

Is there a quick easy way to print

```
-$8.2
```

Comment: Perhaps you should try [`Locale::Currency::Format`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Locale%3A%3ACurrency%3A%3AFormat).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sprintf("%s\$%0.2f", $Profit >=0 ? "" : "-", abs($Profit))
```

5.14+:

```
sprintf("%0.2f", $Profit) =~ s/^-?\K/\$/r
```

Comment: @Jean `\K` keeps the previous match out of the matched substring. It is essentially a variable-length lookbehind. The `\K` itself is quite a bit older than 5.14; the special thing here is the `/r` which returns the substituted string instead of modifying the original.

Comment: lose the ^\ before the -; otherwise just what I was going to say :)

Comment: @ysth, I left in the `^`, but removed the "noisy" `\ `.

Comment: ok, but it is completely unnecessary; /-?\K/ will always match at the start of any string.

Comment: @ysth, It's self-documenting. Much much more readable than omitting it.

Comment: Is substitution inside a `sprintf` generated string a 5.14+ feature too ?

Comment: @Jean, no idea what that means. (Substitution is an action, so it can't be found in strings. You might have meant "substitution operator", but those aren't found in strings either.)

Comment: `my $str = 'abc'; printf("%s",sprintf("%s",$str)=~s/a/b/);` gives the error `Can't modify sprintf in substitution (s///) at ./test.pl line 13, near "s/a/b/)"
Execution of ./test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.` in `5.8.8`

Comment: Sorry, rushed earlier comment. It's valid syntax, but it makes no sense. Even if the value returned by `sprintf` was modifyable, what's the point of modifying a value you never get to do anything with? the equivalent would be `my $s = sprintf("%0.2f", $Profit); $s =~ s/^-?\K/\$/; $s`